# PIC16F628A 16x4 LCD problem while using MPLABX

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplab, mplabx

I'm trying to connect a 16x4 LCD with a PIC16F628A, but I cannot get any response on the display, the display is blank. I put on a LED for indicating whether the time was right, and apparently everything is correct. I tested it on Proteus and it also does not work.

My code and library are below:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: Leonardo
 *
 * Created on 11 de Março de 2014, 00:15
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "GenericTypeDefs.h"
#include <xc.h>
#include "LCD_lib.h"

// DEFINIÇÃO DOS FUSES
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSCIO      // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator: High-speed crystal/resonator on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT and RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
//#pragma config FOSC = INTOSCIO        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator: High-speed crystal/resonator on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT and RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = ON       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // RA5/MCLR/VPP Pin Function Select bit (RA5/MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage Programming Enable bit (RB4/PGM pin has digital I/O function, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = ON        // Data EE Memory Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection off)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

#define __XTAL_FREQ 4000000

#define LED_TRIS  TRISAbits.TRISA0
#define LED       PORTAbits.RA0

void delay_ms(long mili);
void delay_us(long micro);

/*
 * 
 */
int main (void){

      lcd_inicia(0x28, 0x0f, 0x06);      // Inicializa LCD
     lcd_limpa_tela();                 // Limpa LCD
     LED_TRIS = 0;
     LED = 0;
//  Prcessamento

        while(TRUE){
            LED = 1;
              lcd_posicao(1,1);
     imprime_string_lcd("Tensao Entrada AN0");
       lcd_posicao(2,2);
            lcd_escreve_dado('A');
            delay_ms(1000);
            LED = 0;
            delay_ms(1000);
        }
}

//*******************FUNÇÃO DELAY EM MILI-SEGUNDOS*******************////
// conta 4mhz/4 = 1mhz T = 1/1mhz = 1us para se obter 1ms então temos:
// então 1ms/1us = 1000 ciclos.
void delay_ms(long mili)
{
   while(mili > 0)
   {
      _delay(1000);//1ms com clock de 20mhz = 5000
      mili--;      //1ms com clock de 4mhz = 1000
   }

}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//*******************FUNÇÃO DELAY EM MICRO-SEGUNDOS*******************////
// conta 4mhz/4 = 1mhz T = 1/1mhz = 1us para se obter 1ms então temos:
// então 1us/1us = 1 ciclo.
void delay_us(long micro)
{
   while(micro > 0)
   {
      _delay(1);//1us com clock de 20mhz = 5
      micro--;//1us com clock de 4mhz = 1
   }

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* 
 * File:   LCD_lib.h
 * Author: bruno
 *
 * Created on 20 de Agosto de 2013, 14:25
 */

#ifndef LCD_LIB_H
#define LCD_LIB_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* LCD_LIB_H */

/*********************************************************************************************************
******************************************BIBLIOTECA DISPLAY LCD******************************************
**                                                                                                       *
**                    Esta biblioteca contém as funções de controle do display LCD.                      *
**                                                                                                       *
**  Livro: Microcontroladores PIC18 - Aprenda e Programe em Linguagem C.                                 *
**  Autor: Alberto Noboru Miyadaira                                                                      *
**  Versão: v0.1                                                                                         *
**  Data: 12/03/2011                                                                                     *
*********************************************************************************************************/
#include <plib/delays.h>

//#ifndef Fosc
 // #define Fosc 8 //Define a frequência do oscilador. Este valor deve corresponder a frequência do oscilador utilizado pelo PIC18.
//#endif
// Os nome definidos são os próprios nomes dos pinos do display LCD.
#define B7 PORTBbits.RB7 //Define o nome B7 para a estrutra.
#define E_B7 TRISBbits.TRISB7=1;
#define S_B7 TRISBbits.TRISB7=0;
#define B6 PORTBbits.RB6 //Define o nome B6 para a estrutra.
#define E_B6 TRISBbits.TRISB6=1;
#define S_B6 TRISBbits.TRISB6=0;
#define B5 PORTBbits.RB5 //Define o nome B5 para a estrutra.
#define E_B5 TRISBbits.TRISB5=1;
#define S_B5 TRISBbits.TRISB5=0;
#define B4 PORTBbits.RB4 //Define o nome B4 para a estrutra.
#define E_B4 TRISBbits.TRISB4=1;
#define S_B4 TRISBbits.TRISB4=0;
#define E  PORTBbits.RB3  //Define o nome E para a estrutra.
#define E_E TRISBbits.TRISB3=1;
#define S_E TRISBbits.TRISB3=0;
//#define RW PORTBbits.RB2//Define o nome RW para a estrutra.
//#define E_RW TRISBbits.TRISB2=1;
//#define S_RW TRISBbits.TRISB2=0;
#define RS PORTBbits.RB1 //Define o nome RS para a estrutra.
#define E_RS TRISBbits.TRISB1=1;
#define S_RS TRISBbits.TRISB1=0;

void gera_atraso_us(unsigned int atraso)//adaptado para Fosc de 20MHz
{
//  do
//  {
//    atraso--;
//  }while (atraso>0);
       while(atraso > 0)
   {
      _delay(1);//1us com clock de 20mhz = 5
      atraso--;//1us com clock de 4mhz = 1
   }
}

//void delay_us(long micro)
//{
//   while(micro > 0)
//   {
//      _delay(5);//1us com clock de 20mhz = 5
//      micro--;//1us com clock de 20mhz = 4
//   }
//
//}

unsigned char lcd_envia_controle (unsigned char instrucao_dado, unsigned int escrita_leitura, unsigned char dado, unsigned int atraso_us)
{
/*
instrucao_dado = 0 //Instrução.
instrucao_dado = 1 //Dado.
escrita_leitura = 1 //Leitura.
escrita_leitura = 0 //Escrita.
*/
unsigned char dado_entrada=0;

//Configura os pinos de dados/controle, como saída.
S_B7;
S_B6;
S_B5;
S_B4;
S_E;
//S_RW;
S_RS;

RS = instrucao_dado; //Informa se é um comando ou dado.
//RW = escrita_leitura; //Informa se é escrita ou leitura.

        if(escrita_leitura == 0)
        {
                B7 = dado>>7;//B7 recebe o bit 7 da variável dado.
                B6 = dado>>6;//B6 recebe o bit 6 da variável dado.
                B5 = dado>>5;//B5 recebe o bit 5 da variável dado.
                B4 = dado>>4;//B4 recebe o bit 4 da variável dado.

                E = 1;//Habilita o Display LCD.
                gera_atraso_us(2); //Gera um delay de 2us.
                E = 0; //Desabilita o Display LCD.

                B7 = dado>>3;//B7 recebe o bit 3 da variável dado.
                B6 = dado>>2;//B6 recebe o bit 2 da variável dado.
                B5 = dado>>1;//B5 recebe o bit 1 da variável dado.
                B4 = dado;//B4 recebe o bit 0 da variável dado.

                E = 1;//Habilita o Display LCD.
                gera_atraso_us(2); //Gera um delay de 2us.
                E = 0; //Desabilita o Display LCD.

                gera_atraso_us(atraso_us); //Gera um delay de xus. MAX 255 ciclos de máquina

                return 0;
        }
        else
        {
                //Configura os pinos de dados, como entrada.
                E_B7;
                E_B6;
                E_B5;
                E_B4;

                E = 1;//Habilita o Display LCD.
          gera_atraso_us(2); //Gera um delay de 2us.

                dado_entrada = B7;
                dado_entrada = dado_entrada<<1 | B6;
                dado_entrada = dado_entrada<<1 | B5;
                dado_entrada = dado_entrada<<1 | B4;

                E = 0; //Desabilita o Display LCD.
                E = 1;//Habilita o Display LCD.
                gera_atraso_us(2); //Gera um delay de 2us.

                dado_entrada = dado_entrada<<1 | B7;
                dado_entrada = dado_entrada<<1 | B6;
                dado_entrada = dado_entrada<<1 | B5;
                dado_entrada = dado_entrada<<1 | B4;

                E = 0; //Desabilita o Display LCD.

                gera_atraso_us(atraso_us); //Gera um delay de xus. MAX 255 ciclos de máquina

                return dado_entrada;
        }
}

//Limpa a tela e coloca o cursor na linha um e coluna um do display.
void lcd_limpa_tela ( )
{
        lcd_envia_controle (0,0,0x01,2000);
}

//Coloca o cursor na linha um e coluna um do display.
void lcd_cursor_home ( )
{
        lcd_envia_controle (0,0,0x02,2000);
}

//Desloca o cursor para a direita ou esquerda.
void lcd_desloca_cursor(unsigned char direita_esquerda)
{
/*
0 - Desloca o cursor para a direita.
1 - Desloca o cursor para a esquerda.
*/
unsigned char cursor[2] = {0x14, 0x10};
        lcd_envia_controle (0,0,cursor[direita_esquerda],40);
}

//Desloca a mensagem para a direita ou esquerda.
void lcd_desloca_mensagem(unsigned char direita_esquerda)
{
/*
0 - Desloca a mensagem para a direita.
1 - Desloca a mensagem para a esquerda.
*/
unsigned char cursor[2] = {0x1c, 0x18};
        lcd_envia_controle (0,0,cursor[direita_esquerda],40);
}

//Liga/Desliga o cursor/display.
void lcd_LD_cursor (unsigned char config)
{
/*
0 - Desliga o cursor.
1 - Desliga o display.
2 - Liga o cursor com alternância.
3 - Liga o display e o cursor.
4 - Liga o display e o cursor piscante.
*/
unsigned char cursor [5] = {0x0c, 0x08, 0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0d};
        lcd_envia_controle (0,0,cursor[config],40);
}

//Coloca o cursor em uma determinada posição do LCD.
void lcd_posicao(unsigned char linha, unsigned char coluna)
{
        switch (linha)
        {
                case 1:
                        lcd_envia_controle (0,0,0x80+coluna-1,40);
                        break;
                case 2:
                        lcd_envia_controle (0,0,0xc0+coluna-1,40);
                        break;
                case 3:
                        lcd_envia_controle (0,0,0x94+coluna-1,40);
                        break;
                case 4:
                        lcd_envia_controle (0,0,0xd4+coluna-1,40);
                        break;
        }
}

//Escreve um caractere ou símbolo no display.
void lcd_escreve_dado(unsigned char dado)
{
        lcd_envia_controle (1,0,dado,45);
}

//Retorna o caractere presente na posição do cursor.
unsigned char lcd_le_dado( )
{
        return lcd_envia_controle (1,1,0,45);
}

//Retorna o valor do status + contador de endereço.
unsigned char lcd_status ( )
{
        return lcd_envia_controle (0,1,0,40);
}

//Envia String para o Display LCD.
//void imprime_string_lcd(const rom char *s_caracteres)
void imprime_string_lcd(unsigned char *s_caracteres)
{
        while (*s_caracteres!=0)
        {
                lcd_escreve_dado(*s_caracteres);
                s_caracteres++;
        }
}

//Envia uma matriz de dados para o Display LCD.
void imprime_buffer_lcd( char *s_caracteres, unsigned char tamanho_buffer)
{
        while (tamanho_buffer--)
        {
                lcd_escreve_dado(*s_caracteres);
                s_caracteres++;
        }
}

//Inicializa o display LCD alfanumérico.
void lcd_inicia( unsigned char conf1, unsigned char conf2, unsigned char conf3)
{
/*
Configuração do display LCD:

(0x28)
- Comunicação 4 vias
- Display com 2 linhas
- Matriz 8x5

(0x0C)
- Liga display
- Cursor piscante

(0x06)
- Desloca o cursor para a direita quando um caractere for inserido.
*/
unsigned char config_LCD[6] = {0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
unsigned char repeticao;

config_LCD[2] = conf1;
config_LCD[3] = conf2;
config_LCD[4] = conf3;

//Configura os pinos de dados/controle, como saída.
S_B7;
S_B6;
S_B5;
S_B4;
S_E;
//S_RW;
S_RS;

RS = 0; //Instrução.
//RW = 0; //Escrita.
E = 0; //Desabilita LCD.

        gera_atraso_us(20000); //Gera um atraso de 20ms.

        for( repeticao = 0 ; repeticao < 3 ; repeticao++ )
        {
                B7 = config_LCD[0]>>3; //B7 recebe o bit 3 do elemento presente na posição 0 da matriz config_LCD.
                B6 = config_LCD[0]>>2; //B6 recebe o bit 2 do elemento presente na posição 0 da matriz config_LCD.
                B5 = config_LCD[0]>>1; //B5 recebe o bit 1 do elemento presente na posição 0 da matriz config_LCD.
                B4 = config_LCD[0];    //B4 recebe o bit 0 do elemento presente na posição 0 da matriz config_LCD.

                E = 1;//Habilita o Display LCD.
                gera_atraso_us(2); //Gera um delay de 2us.
                E = 0; //Desabilita o Display LCD.

                gera_atraso_us(5000); //Gera um delay de 5ms.
        }

B7 = config_LCD[1]>>3; //B7 recebe o bit 3 do elemento presente na posição 1 da matriz config_LCD.
B6 = config_LCD[1]>>2; //B6 recebe o bit 2 do elemento presente na posição 1 da matriz config_LCD.
B5 = config_LCD[1]>>1; //B5 recebe o bit 1 do elemento presente na posição 1 da matriz config_LCD.
B4 = config_LCD[1];    //B4 recebe o bit 0 do elemento presente na posição 1 da matriz config_LCD.

E = 1;//Habilita o Display LCD.
gera_atraso_us(2); //Gera um delay de 2us.
E = 0; //Desabilita o Display LCD.

gera_atraso_us(40); //Gera um delay de 40us.

lcd_envia_controle (0,0,config_LCD[2],40);
lcd_envia_controle (0,0,config_LCD[3],40);
lcd_envia_controle (0,0,config_LCD[4],40);

lcd_limpa_tela ( );

}
```

Comment: I've formatted the code a little but it is still quite lengthy. Maybe you could make a smaller cut-down example of something like initialising the display and displaying a single character? If you could translate the comments to English that might also help getting an answer.

Comment: May be Portuguese will be difficult for people here to understand

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the delay, but the problem was solved, the errors were in the functions of delay, and some were wrong command being sent to the display, thanks.

Comment: It's worth adding more detail to the answer such as the fixed delay code and details on the wrong commands so that if anyone else has a similar problem in the future it might be a useful reference.